# Laravel Authentication Using Linux User Credentials

Tags: linux, laravel, authentication

As the title says, is it possible to utilize Linux user credentials, particularly Ubuntu for Laravel Auth?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you mean by 'Linux user credentials'? Do you mean ssh credentials? Or just the normal Linux login? Or what exactly?

Comment: @ChadFisher The normal user log in credentials, I mean.

Comment: An example would be users "root", "www-data", etc.

Comment: So for example, you build a website: test-auth.com (On the Laravel Framework which sits on top of an Ubuntu Server). Then you add users to the Ubuntu server on the back end.  Then using the web login interface at test-auth.com/login you enter those Ubuntu user credentials that exist on the server.   Is this the general use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my comment is correct in assuming the credentials you want to validate via Laravel are on the Unbuntu server its running on, why not overload the authentication on the login controller?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        //Normal Authentication 
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }

        //Now check Unbuntu credentials
        //Read /etc/passwd to find the user
        //Read /etc/shadow to validate the SHA encrypted password
        //If successful, maybe use something like Auth::loginUsingId(1)
        //Where 1 is the predefined ID of any user loggin in from Ubuntu
    }
}
```

Comment: Loved it.! Perfect.